# Is there a way to generate a unicode by putting a '\' in front of a string with python?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

Here is a normal way to print a unicode.

```
print('\u2080')
```

which outputs a subscripts character

```
₀
```

string format gives some material

```
for i in range(3):
    print('u208{}'.format(i))
```

outputs

```
u2080
u2081
u2082
```

I am trying to generate a unicode by putting a '\' in front of these.

I think I am almost there.

```
print('\\'+'u2080')
```

outputs

```
\u2080
```

How do I do next, to have this output the subscripts ₀ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ord` to transform the unicode character into an integer, apply your transformation (bitwise operators might be handy here depending on what you're doing), and then `chr` to convert back to the unicode character:

```
>>> print(list(chr(ord('\u2080') | i) for i in range(10)))
['₀', '₁', '₂', '₃', '₄', '₅', '₆', '₇', '₈', '₉']
```

You can also skip the `ord` and go strait from int to character:

```
>>> print(list(chr(0x2080 + i) for i in range(10)))
['₀', '₁', '₂', '₃', '₄', '₅', '₆', '₇', '₈', '₉']
```

Comment: No need to use a bitwie operation there, as a simple addition will yield consistent results for character ranges that go beyond the last digit (and will work as offset if the last digit on the base character is not zero)

Comment: @jsbueno you're right. Addition is the best way to go. I present both options here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, working only with strings, without resorting to extracting the number of the codepoint and using the `chr` function, it is possible to create the correspondent unicode characters:

The module `codecs` in the stdlib have functions to register and get text codecs: the mappings from and to text to bytes, and some other text or byte transforms.

Among those transforms there is the `unicode_escape` character. It can be used directly when converting a bytes object to text using the `bytes.decode` method, but it also can be retrieved using `codecs.getdecoder("unicode_escape")` and convert text to  text.

Therefore it is possible to do:

```
In [139]: import codecs                                                                                                                                

In [140]: esc = codecs.getdecoder("unicode_escape")                                                                                                    

In [141]: for i in range(10): 
     ...:     print(esc(f"\\u208{i}")[0], end=" ") 
     ...:      
     ...:      
     ...:                                                                                                                                              
₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉
```

The call to the decoder returns a tuple with the result and the number of input characters consumed. The `[0]`  after the call retrieves only the converted result.

(Above I used the "f-string" syntax that superseeded the `.format` method for almost all uses in Python 3.6)

Ordinarily one will prefer using the `chr` built-in, though - as it avoids juggling with string formatting and can deal with the numbers directly. (if we wanted more than 16 characters starting at a certain codepoint, the method above would not work as it is, for example).

```
print(" ".join(chr(0x2080 + i) for i in range(29)))
```

will print:

₀ ₁ ₂ ₃ ₄ ₅ ₆ ₇ ₈ ₉ ₊ ₋ ₌ ₍ ₎ ₏ ₐ ₑ ₒ ₓ ₔ ₕ ₖ ₗ ₘ ₙ ₚ ₛ ₜ